# Having trouble keeping element rotation consistent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rotation, transform

For a project I'm currently working on I need to have a wheel for which it is essential to have 1:1 rotation.

So far I have gotten a click and drag rotation mechanism working, but the problem is that it is very erratic, in the sense that I've had it work flawlessly and then at one point (without me changing the code) it would suddenly mess up and fail to rotate properly, even after page refresh and cache clearing.

I first noticed this after I moved it from my local server to a live test server. Another strange characteristic is that it spins perfectly while the mouse is outside the boundary of the wheel, and starts messing up when back within (I detect mouse movement with a mousetrap in the form of an invisible SVG circle perfectly overlapping the image).

The whole thing is very simple:

```
$('.mouse_trap').mousedown(function(){
        intervalvar = setInterval(monitorClicks, 24);
    }).mouseup(function(){
        clearInterval(intervalvar);
    })
```

When the person clicks and drags on the wheel, it sets of and stops a setInterval accordingly (in the meantime a seperate function is monitoring mouse position).

```
function monitorClicks(){
    xrel = xpos - midx;
    yrel = -(ypos - midy);

    a = Math.atan2(yrel,xrel);
    a = a *  (180 / Math.PI);
    a = -a;

    roulette.css({
        '-webkit-transform' : 'rotate(' + a + 'deg)',
        '-ms-transform' : 'rotate(' + a + 'deg)',
        '-o-transform' : 'rotate(' + a + 'deg)',
        '-moz-transform' : 'rotate(' + a + 'deg)',
        'transform' : 'rotate(' + a + 'deg)'
    });

    console.log(a); 

}
```

I find the mouse position, turn the midpoint into the center of the circle and then using the coordinates apply atan2 to get my angle.

You can find the experiment here:

http://www.techgoldmine.com/spinny_thing/

Comment: Please add meaningful code here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: It looks like `midy` is a little off. Could it be possible that you're using the center of the window as opposed to the center of the roulette wheel?

Comment: @svckr it's the center of the window that's being used.

Comment: @svckr 
Okay, that's definitely it, I'll quickly patch some things up...